# Missing intellisense when importing .ts file in .js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, es6-modules, tsx

I try to use [tsx](https://github.com/esbuild-kit/tsx) to run a NodeJS application made of JavaScript and Typescript modules. The JavaScript modules are ESM, not CommonJS. For example I have these files:

```
// provider.ts
export funcA(p: unknown): unknown {...}

// consumer.js
import * as provider from "./provider.ts"

provider.funcA("foo");
```

It runs very well with tsx. VSCode's intellisense works well in TS file but it doesn't in JS file. When I hover `provider` it shows `import provider` and I have no completion whatsoever.
Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
  },
  "include": [
    <the directory containing both JS and TS files>
  ],
}
```

How can I make Intellisense work in VSCode for TS imports in my JS files?

Comment: you'll have to have it compile the ts into js - javascript just can't load a ts file

Comment: Like I said, I can run my code with tsx without issues. My question is only about intellisense in VSCode. VSCode embeds TypeScript compiler so it should be able to understand both JS and TS and provide type information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. It seems TypeScript can not understand when I import a `.ts` module.

I had to remove the `.ts` part of the import. I had to add `"moduleResolution": "Node"` to my `tsconfig.json` to remove resolve errors.

I also got some trouble with my eslint configuration. I installed packages `@typescript-eslint/parser` and `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` and added this to my `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"extends": [
  ...
  "plugin:import/typescript"
],
...
"settings": {
  "node": {
    "tryExtensions": [".js", ".node", ".ts"]
  }
}
```

Now it works. I get full Intellisense in my JS file.